# Custom simulator rule disappears on Petrel 2012

Tags: ocean

I've got a custom simulator rule. It all works fine on Petrel 2011 but the following happens on Petrel 2012.

If I open Petrel with no project, the rule is listed under add rules in the Make Development Strategy process.

If I then open a project that contains an old version of the custom rule (defined in a different assembly that no longer exists), the rule is not listed under add rules in the Make Development Strategy process. Opening the project does report an exception about the missing old assembly.

Why does this happen, does anyone have an ideas?

Neal

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that our new custom simulator was not selected when opening the existing project and therefore the rule is not listed.

As this problem does not affect Petrel 2011, it appears that Petrel 2011 displays all rules and Petrel 2012 filters to only display valid rules for the selected simulators.